# android how change background action bar

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar, styles

Hi i would change my actionbar background color. I've found a lot of tutorial but when i launch my app it crashes giving me error message.

This is what i've done.
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".UserActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.securepassword.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="user" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AddItemActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.securepassword.UserActivity" 
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="add_item" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

UserActivity and AddItemActivity are the activities where actionbar appears.

I have created my personal style in /res/values-v11/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#0086D4</item>
</style>
```

when i start UserActivity my app crashes giving me this error:

```
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.securepassword/com.example.securepassword.UserActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at com.example.securepassword.UserActivity.onCreate(UserActivity.java:17)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-10 12:53:08.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15095):    ... 11 more
```

The problem appears when in androidmanifest i use MyTheme like style for both activities..what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using code in your `Activity` like this:

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
            Color.parseColor("#0086D4"));
ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

To change the color of text on `ActionBar` use this:

```
ab.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#YOUR_COLORCODE'>ActionBarTitle </font>"));
```

**OR**

```
int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
    if (title != null) {
        title.setTextColor(YOUR COLOR );
    }
}
```

Comment: i've tried this code and works but i need use style.xml file because i need to change also color text of actionbar..is it possible programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You have answer in exception message

```
    You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Use Theme.AppCompat.

Additionally you can use toolbar to customize you action bar
You can add  it in layout xml such as standard view and set it in your activity by setSupportActionBar(toolbarObject) method as is shown below

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
<!-- your layout -->

 </LinearLayout>
```

YourActivty.class

```
 public class YourActivty extends ActionBarActivity {

   Toolbar mToolbar;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      // configure toolbar stuff
      setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
   }
 }
```

But when you want to use toolbar. You have to use Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar theme

Answer (score 0):

Change the inheritance of your main activity to Activity (import android.app.Activity) , i think it solves the problem with using custom theme

Comment: where should i change it?

Comment: in the imports..on top of the class..what is your Activity inheriting from? ..ex public class MyActivity extends Activity{

Comment: hello i just noticed your custom theme is deriving from the wrong parent i think...try change from parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" to parent="Theme.AppCompat" in your styles.xml